# Is there a way to scale x-axis on bar chart (using eCharts) so the 0 is always in the middle?

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

My problem is that I have a lot of different data displayed on the bar chart on user demand.

This is how the graph looks now.

[image: Graph now]

What I want to achieve is to kind of scale the x-axis that way so the 0 is always in the middle of the chart. That way when I change the data and let's say on positive side max value is 20% and negative -60% x-axis 0 won't be on the right side of the chart but rather in the middle of it.

I was checking eCharts documentation but I didn't find any solution. Is there a way to achieve that without changing the series data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set min and max values for the axis.

```
xAxis: {
 max: 100,
 min: 0,
}
```